# java.lang.VerifyError: Stack shape inconsistent

Tags: java

The following code was working fine on `java 1.6` and `maven 2.2.1`:

```
public class GTMEnrollmentOutputRecord extends com.ibm.ivj.eab.record.cobol.CobolRecord implements java.io.Serializable
{
   public GTMEnrollmentOutputRecord() throws RecordException
   {
      try {
         //Getting error at the below line
         GTMEnrollmentOutputRecordType dynRecType = new GTMEnrollmentOutputRecordType();
```

After upgrading to `Java 1.7` and `Maven 3.3.3` for `IBM Webspehere 8.5.5.3` I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent
```

Comment: Please add the full exception and output of `mvn dependency:tree` command

Comment: [Id : eCAFE][Loc : com.hi.ehouse.services.exceptionhandling.safetynet.ContextCapableSafetyNet.handle(Throwable cause, String identifier)][Desc : Safety Net exception message: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=com/hi/gps/viewdata/gpmru/GTMEnrollmentOutputRecordType, method=<init>()V, pc=19]

Comment: Full stack trace, please updated your answer and don't use comments

Comment: updated text and formated

Comment: And just in case you are using a IBM JRE to also run your stuff ... they are notoriously picky about such things, and sometimes one has to "simply" go in and use some --noverify (?) option to the JVM to suppress the corresponding checking.

Comment: @GhostCat, yes we are using IBM JRE, Can you please suggest where to specify --noverify option in JVM

Comment: I am getting this error for one of the class only...other classes are working fine. class code already shared.

Comment: I think there is a `-noverify` option that you can give on the command line, that will disable all such verification. You shouldnt use that in a production setup, but it is worth trying to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Java 7 changed the format of the stack frame and introduced format checks in [JSR 202: Java Class File Specification Update](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=202). The most likely cause of this error is a 3rd party library that generates bytecode in older, Java 6 format e.g. [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) or [CGLIB](https://github.com/cglib/cglib).

You need to inspect your project dependencies and ensure that all of them are supporting Java 7.

Comment: How can i check that project dependencies are supporting java 7 or not. Is there any command to check?.

Comment: @ShoaibBagwan nope, you have to find the docs or release notes for each 3rd party dependency you are using and see which version works with Java 7.